# draw a large graph with many nodes and edges with igraph

Tags: python, graph, drawing, social-networking, igraph

I'm trying to visualize a big data set of nodes and edges and I have two files: `nodes.txt` and `edges.txt` and I want draw a graph for them. it's got 403,394 nodes and 3,387,388 edges. good to know I generate them randomly.

So I decide using `igraph` python to draw it by layout and plot but when I try to draw a simple graph with few edges it works but with this huge data set it got an memory error and doesn't work right. I want some help to draw a graph from my edge list with `igraph`. or maybe there is some better way to do, so suggest it to me.

I use layout with `Drl` algorithm and use the function plot.

Comment: Some remarks/questions: 1: Why do you want to plot it (especially as it's randomly generated). 2: Why not subsample it? Just build another set, and add each node with a probability of 0.1. Then iterate over edges, check if nodes exist, if yes, add edge with probability of 0.1. 3: A more machine-learning like approach for subsampling: use clustering on the nodes to select a smaller set = subsampling. Some clustering algorithms will struggle though. 4: Care about the used layout.algorithm. What complexity does it have? Quadratic? That's bad!

Comment: It's my final project on university and I should plot it just for sacrifice my master. It's a good idea to subsampl it but one question : what do you mean by sampling with probability 0.1? clustring? maybe good but I have told to just visualize it and I don't know what to do! and about complexity I don't know what complexity it has. Cannot find anything about it!